# Limit comparison Test for series 1/(n^2 * log n ) converge or diverge

Tags: limits

[image]

Doubt  - used inequality, $1/(n^2 \log n) < 1/ n^2$ will be true only for $n > 10$ as $\log n < 1$ for $1 < n < 10 $. but here summation is running from $n=  2$ to infinite
 please check whether the solution which is arrived is correct with the correct procedure.

Comment: Is it the decimal log?

Comment: yes it is log base 10

Comment: What is imortant for convergence or divergence is  the *asymptotic* behaviour. You may modify a finite number of terms in a series, it won't modify its convergence or divergence.

Comment: In the title you are referring to LCT but it seems you are using direct comparison test. Can you clarify this point?

Comment: well in one of my book, there are two types are given under the title LCT, type 1  - as i have done above and type 2 - lim (Un/Vn)  - L > 0

Comment: and I did not used type 2 because lim Un/Vn tends to 0 as n tends to infinity , but to use the properties (if Vn converges than Un too )limit should not be equal to 0 that's why I was confused whether to use that or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is right, we have that

$$\frac{\frac1{n^2 \log n}}{\frac1{n^2}}=\frac1{\log n} \to 0$$

and therefore by LCT the given series converges.

Note that the initial values are not relevant here since we are interested to the behaviour for $n$ larg and also the inequality $1/(n^2 \log n) < 1/ n^2$ is not an issue when we use LCT.

Comment: In this case 1/log  n is strictly decreasing sequence and as n tends to infinite, 1/log n tend to 0 , but to use lct properties isn't it should not be equal to 0, example  to say if Vn converges implies Un converges

Comment: @AbhishekVerma This is not true, for the convergent case the LCT also works when the limit is equal to $0$. Refer also to [here](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html). I don't know why this point is often not clarified.

Comment: that's new, thanks alot

Comment: @AbhishekVerma You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

When testing for convergence,
any initial part of the sum
can be ignored,
since it does not
affect the result.

In your case,
the initial 10
(or 100 or $10^{10}$)
can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, here, $\log$ is the *natural* logarithm. Anyway, it follows from the comparison test that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n^2\log n}$. Therefore, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2\log n}$ converges too.